# Purescript: Halogen HTML DSL only Renders "id" tags

Tags: purescript, halogen

I'm using `purescript-halogen` `v0.12.0`, and I can't figure out why only the `id` tag is rendering.

This occurs even with supposedly well supported elements, like `div`.

Example:

`render = div [ id_ "some-id", name "some-name ] []`

A div will be created, but only with an `id` attribute. This occurs with elements in `Halogen.HTML` as well as `Halogen.HTML.Indexed`.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

=============================================================

Reproduce the issue with the following.

```
pulp init
bower i purescript-halogen
npm i virtual-dom
```

============

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)

import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML (div, text)
import Halogen.HTML.Properties (id_, name, pixels, height, width)
import Halogen.Util (awaitBody, runHalogenAff)

type State = Int
data Query a = Toggle a

ui :: forall g. (Functor g) => H.Component State Query g
ui = H.component { render, eval }
  where
    render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
    render st = div [ id_ "my-id", name "my-name", height (pixels 3), width (pixels 4) ] [ text "here!" ]

    eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query g
    eval (Toggle next) = pure next

main :: forall e. Eff (H.HalogenEffects e) Unit
main = runHalogenAff $ do
  body <- awaitBody
  H.runUI ui 0 body
```

Comment: I assume the name attribute is only used for HTML forms, and is ignored on <div>s. Have you tried to use the name on another element, e.g. a <button>?

Comment: @stholzm I believe if user7428320 isn't using anything from the Indexed elements, there should be no reason for the attributes to be ignored. I can also confirm that the attributes do not display when rolling your own custom tags, like `svg`. If there is some type check on the html DSL going on, it should be reflected in the compiler, which it isn't. I have not figured out why yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring as `name` is not a [valid property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#htmlelement) to apply to a `div`, nor are `width` or `height` - if you're using the `Indexed` elements and properties you'll see there's a type error when trying to set `width` or `height`. Try changing the `div` for an `input` and you'll see the properties applied as they should be.

The indexed elements do allow setting a `name` on the `div` however, which is a bug.

The reason these properties do not show in the rendered HTML is they are being set as properties rather than attributes. Properties must exist in the javascript interface for the element otherwise they are ignored. This isn't a Halogen thing so much as the DOM.