# Purescript Halogen: Defining Custom HTML Elements

Tags: purescript, virtual-dom, halogen

I'm having difficulties similar to this unanswered question: [Purescript: Halogen HTML DSL only Renders "id" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688580/purescript-halogen-html-dsl-only-renders-id-tags)

I'm trying to define a new HTML element. In particular, I would like to display an `svg` elem and `image` element with some new tags, like `x_`, and `y_`.

I'm defining the element like so:

```
image :: forall p i. Array (Prop i) -> Array (HTML p i) -> HTML p i
image xs = element (tagName "image") xs

image_ :: forall p i. Array (HTML p i) -> HTML p i
image_ = image []
```

And then attributes I would like:

```
image :: forall p i. Array (Prop i) -> Array (HTML p i) -> HTML p i
image xs = element (tagName "image") xs

image_ :: forall p i. Array (HTML p i) -> HTML p i
image_ = image []
```

When I create the element, the program compiles, however only the `<image></image>` tags are rendered, without the specified attributes. It seems like the way halogen interfaces with `virtual-dom` does not allow me to do this, however, I'm not sure why.

In general, why can't I just add any attributes to a `div`, `svg`, or `image` element? I'm not using `Halogen.HTML.Indexed` for any of these elements. Is that the problem?? Is the type checker just missing the fact that these combinations are not allowed because I haven't specified them??

In general, I would like to do something even like:

```
customProperty :: forall i. String -> String -> Prop i
customProperty p = prop (propName p) (Just $ attrName p)
```

and then call

`image [ customProperty "myProperty" "myPropertyValue" ] []`

and have that attribute rendered.

========================

Edit: Reading through the source code, it seems that `namespace` has something to do with it, however, I'm not sure how to find the namespace of an already constructed element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attributes you're trying to set are not javascript properties of the tag then you need to use `attr` rather than `prop` to define them. For example, the "class" *attribute* is called `className` as a property, as this is the name of it [in the `Element` interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-element).

Comment: Although this solution allows me to see the attributes inside of the newly created tag, in this case, an `svg`, it does not actually render the nodes to the dom. Namely, `<svg><line ...></line></svg` does not display a line, and the svg element is unable to be styled/seen by the css. I'm assuming I can't just use `svg :: forall p i. Array (Prop i) -> Array (HTML p i) -> HTML p i`
`svg props = element (tagName "svg") props`. Do I need to use `halogen-purescript-vdom`?